# Python - Can't import Seaborn

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I'm running iPhyton Notebooks and I'm trying to import the Seaborn package. When I try to import it from the Terminal, it loads up fine, but when I import it through iPython Notebooks, it give me the following error.
I have even tried to re-install Seaborn using both Conda and Pip inside iPython notebooks and still it wont work.
Any idea why?

Thanks.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-417274a1ae6c> in <module>()
      1 get_ipython().system(u'conda install seaborn')
      2 get_ipython().system(u'pip install seaborn')
----> 3 import seaborn as sb
      4 

ImportError: No module named seaborn
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: did you install ipython with conda? You may have to do a `conda install notebook` to make sure ipython sees your library.

Comment: tried that and it will wont work. Still the same error.

Comment: then please add the output of `which -a pip`, `which -a python` and `which -a ipython`

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I had similar problems. Which version of ipython are you using?

Comment: I do not know if this will solve your problem or if you have already solved it, but this typically happens to me if I try to do install anything from my office since there is a firewall which blocks auto install. The work around I use is manually download the library and then install

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
import sys
print sys.path
sys.path.append('<path to package in your syste>')

import seaborn
```

In my Ubuntu 14.4LTS the packages get installed in the following folder

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

So I simply add the package path at run time

Answer (score 0):

Donit install Ipython on all your system. Install it only in the environments you want it. Otherwise Ipython will look for modules in the default path instead of the environment's path.

This is probably where your ipython is looking:

```
/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/
```

It should be looking for modules here:

```
/home/user/anaconda2/envs/name-of-env/lib/python3.4/
```

To check the path you type:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

Answer (score 0):

Try entering the following in your terminal:

```
conda install seaborn
```

It will install seaborn and make it available for you to import into your notebook

Answer (score 0):

Open anaconda prompt and Type

```
pip install seaborn
```